# react-native... how to import javascripts into my project .. that are not in the npmjs

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an application and I need to do an integration with a js library.
this library is not in npmjs ...

the library works perfectly in html ...

how can I use this library with react-native

Comment: Please, be more specific. What have you tried? What is the name of the library?

Comment: Just add it to your source code in a separate folder and import it where you are using it?

Comment: "Can't find variable: document"...

I did as I said .. but it returns error. "document"